# Computed fields in DS.Model not working with DS.RESTAdapter in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Calculated field of model does not display while using RestAdapter. Why?

My route and view look like this:

```
App.MyObjRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(params)
  {
      return App.MyObj.find(params.myobjId);
  }
});

App.MyObjView = Ember.View.extend({});
```

I have a DS.Model:

```
App.MyObj = DS.Model.extend({
  first: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  last: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  firstlast: function()
  {
    return this.get('first') + ' ' + this.get('last');
  }.property('first', 'last')
})
```

And a fixture code:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create()
});

App.MyObj.FIXTURES = [
  { 
    id: 1, 
    first: 'Trek', 
    last: 'Bob'
  }
];
```

that i display in a template like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="myTemplate">

{{firstlast}} {{first}} {{last}}

</script>
```

And this works pretty well. I get "Trek Bob Trek Bob" displayed.

But when i preserve the Model:

```
App.MyObj = DS.Model.extend({
  first: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  last: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  firstlast: function()
  {
    return this.get('first') + ' ' + this.get('last');
  }.property('first', 'last')
})
```

and replace fixture code with a RestAdapter like this:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 13,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({url: "myApi"})
});
```

Only `{{first}}` and `{{last}}` is displayed, and `{{firstlast}}` isn't.

How to fix it?

Comment: this seams strange because it should work also with the `RESTAdapter`. Could you try to put a `console.log(...)` in your computed property and see if it get's called when using the `RESTAdapter`?

Comment: I've tried and it is called but this.get('first') returns null. Have u any ideas?

Comment: I found it: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/, the part about underscores, in my project i had big betters in fields and because of some weird reason Ember requires REST to return it in lower letters and with underscore before. And there is no clear explanation what is wrong, no error about it. Very frustrating ohhh...